# How to delete a registry value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, key, registry

i want to know how can i delete a registry value in C# like "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography" and inside Cryptography key i want to delete MachineGuid. i've tried this ("using Microsoft.Win32;")

```
        string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Cryptography";
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value Cannot Be Found");
            }
            else
            {
                key.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
            }
         }
```

But didn't work. (i mean MachineGuid Value was still there)

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: i mean MachineGuid value was still there

Comment: And you didn't get an error, etc?

Comment: Your process would need to be running with admin privileges to do that. It's probably a bad idea to delete that key - it might break something!

Comment: @Matthew Would it? They're accessing HKEY_CURRENT_USER. I second that deleting the key is potentially a bad idea.

Comment: @Llama i saw the message box. Soo prob something is wrong

Comment: @Matthew do i have to specify "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" ?

Comment: i am going to try it in my Virtual Machine so its ok i just need to learn how.

Comment: Ah misread it. Current User should be able to delete things under HKEY_CURRENT_USER without special privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
            string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Cryptography";
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value Cannot Be Found");
            }
            else
            {
                key.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
            }
         }
```

I dont recommend deleting it though lol

Comment: but the think is i always delete machineguid for a game and literally nothing happens : D

Comment: wowowow it worked thx man luv u - no homo

Comment: nice, good luck crushing someones internet

Comment: no no i am using it for unbanning in a game :D

Comment: can i ask one more thing?

Comment: i want to delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\"Random Numbers"

Comment: Everyone has a different number. Like for me its 251792345, for someone else its 34364934. How can i delete that?. Like how can i specify random numbers in c#?

Comment: tbh I dont understand what you are trying to do

Comment: i am basically trying to unban in a game.. and for that i have to delete machine guid and some randomized numbers (key) in registry

Comment: this "randomized number" is not a randomized number since the game finds it somehow, you need to find a pattern, or the way which the game uses to find this key, for example it might start with `Banned` like `Banned4783256483258`